# Having trouble creating a responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar, nav

Having trouble making the nav bar responsive. Due to the desired design I used two ul's with an image in between. This causes the breakpoints to happen at a large size because of the li padding. I would like to move the logo to the left and add a dropdown button to display the navbar options, along with removing the topbar at a mobile display width. Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scalisi Skincare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="build/css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topbar">
            <a href="#">GIVE $10, GET $10</a>
            <a href="#">FREE SHIPPING AND FREE RETURNS ON ORDERS OVER $50+</a>
            <a class="right" href="#">MY ACCOUNT</a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="firstNavSection">
                <li><a href="#">BOB'S CREAM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SCALISI SKINCARE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TINTED</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/logo.PNG" alt="SCALISI"></a>
            <ul class="secondNavSection">
                <li><a href="#">REVIEW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
    .topbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: #7C8DC0;
        padding: 8px 100px;
        a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        flex: 1;
        font-family: calibri;
        font-size: 1em;
        }
        .right {
        text-align: right;
        }
    }
    nav {
        border: 1px solid #dae3e5;
        .firstNavSection {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            top: -10px;
            li {
                display: inline-block;
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0 60px;
                a {
                    font-family: calibri;
                    font-size: 1.5em;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: black;
                }
            }
        }
        a {
            img {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                top: 10px;
            }
        }
        .secondNavSection {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            top: -10px;
            li{
                display: inline-block;
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0 60px;
                a {
                    font-family: calibri;
                    font-size: 1.5em;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: black;
                    i {
                        color: #7C8DC0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should follow the Bootstrap's boilerplate and don't forget to add it's resources.

Comment: @anthrax-xarhtna this is not an answer and is better suited in the comments section of the question

Comment: would love to do that, but because of my current rep I can't write on the comment section. Have a nice day!